Stripe Subscription update ISSUES while Trial still active PHP
Morning , ran into a problem with stripe subscriptions that I cannot identify a solution to. We have a site that offers 14 free trial the first time a customer subscribes to one of our two plans - monthly(14.99) / yearly (149.99) , the issue I keep running into is managing the subscription change using either subscription update or subscription schedule if the subscription is still in those 14 days of trial , for whatever reason there is always an invoice when switching during trial that covers the period the user chose (ex. if the user chose monthly plan they get charged 14.99 immediately when switching then at the next billing 141.77 , but the new billing cycle is correct and does include the trial period as expected ) what i tried so far is :
1 - make a subscription schedule at the end of the trial to switch to the new plan
$phases = array(
    [
    'items' => [
      [
        'price' => $current_price_id,
        'quantity' => 1,
      ],
     ],
    'start_date' => $subscription->current_period_start,
    'end_date' => $free_trial, // End of the current period
    'trial_end' => $free_trial,
    'proration_behavior' => 'none'                        
  ],
  [
    'items' => [
      [
        'price' => $new_price_id,
         'quantity' => 1,
      ],
  ],
    'start_date' => $free_trial, // Start after the current period ends
    'trial_end' => $free_trial,
    'billing_cycle_anchor' => 'period_start',
    'proration_behavior' => 'none',
  ],
);           

2 - update subscription directly if still in the trial phase:
 $stripe->subscriptions->update(
  $current_subscription_id,
   [
'items' => [
[
'id' => $subscription->items->data[0]->id,
'price' => $new_price_id, // New price ID
],
],
'proration_behavior' => 'none',
'trial_end' => $free_trial,//THIS IS A TIMESTAMP I HAVE IN THE DB
'billing_cycle_anchor' => 'unchanged',
],
);

3 - both of the above adding invoice deletion after the change

// If there's an invoice generated during the trial, it needs to be voided
$invoices = \Stripe\Invoice::all(['subscription' => $subscription->id]);
foreach ($invoices->data as $invoice) {
    if ($invoice->status === 'open') {
      // Update invoice status to void
      \Stripe\Invoice::update($invoice->id, ['status' => 'void']);
    }
}

The documentation does not seem to hold an example for doing this , we tried doing this with the portal previously and that behaved even more unpredictably (even with disabled proration etc).
So far the only thing that I managed to figure out is that stripe triggers this event( can be caught in the web-hooks endpoint we setup) - Trial ended for price_xxxxx every time you change a subscription that is in trial and this in turn triggers the first invoice.
I wonder if anyone here has some experience and maybe could help point the error in these approaches.

Ending a trial always resets the billing anchor to be the time the trial ended, so it generates an invoice for upcoming period. (i.e. billing starts when the trial ends).

I am not trying to end a trial , I am trying to keep it active while switching plans and it seems always trigger trial_end when subscription is updated ,even if updated subscription has trial_end set to a timestamp in the future. So you are saying that there is no way to allow a user to switch plans while still trialing ? Say move from monthly to yearly before the first invoice is issued?

It's hard to say in abstract from code without seeing the exact Prices and parameter values you're using(it's more of a question for Stripe Support, not a coding/StackOverflow question). For instance if your "switch" is from a monthly to a weekly Price, that triggers payment as the billing period changes, that's another possible factor. https://docs.stripe.com/billing/subscriptions/upgrade-downgrade#immediate-payment

Since you mention "move from monthly to yearly" maybe that's the issue; in which case you can't avoid that Invoice being created sine it's inherent to when the billing period changes on Stripe. You can consider options like adding negative invoice items or coupons to cancel out the charge on that Invoice, depending on your goals.

Actually it turns out the first code using phases seems to work correctly except it was not applying correctly due to a discrepancy in my logic , where I was wrongly checking the free_trial vs time() instead of the current_period_end , and that introduced the logic error that messed everything up when using Simulation Clocks as the time on stripe was 2026 vs 2024 , thank you for the insights though , yes what you replied is correct from their docs , but only applies to Checkout Sessions / automatic , should be avoidable using schedules and seems it is.
